# How does snakemake threads work, and what is the expected behavior when thread definition is inconsistent?

Tags: python, multithreading, snakemake

Can you help me understand how snakemake handles the threading?

Imagine a case: You are running snakemake on a computer with **10 cores**.

Case 0 (proper use case)

```py
rule someRule0:
    benchmark: "benchmark_result0.tsv"    
    threads: 2
    shell:
        """
        ./sometool --threads {threads}
        """
```

Case 1 (`threads` missing; thus defaults to 1?)

```py
rule someRule1:
    benchmark: "benchmark_result1.tsv"    
    shell:
        """
        ./sometool --threads 2
        """
```

Case 2 (`threads` < actual nthreads we give program as argument)

```py
rule someRule2:
    benchmark: "benchmark_result2.tsv"    
    threads: 1
    shell:
        """
        ./sometool --threads 2
        """
```

Case 3 (`threads` > actual nthreads we give program as argument)

```py
rule someRule3:
    benchmark: "benchmark_result3.tsv"    
    threads: 5
    shell:
        """
        ./sometool --threads 2
        """
```

Case 4 (`threads` asked in total > ncores available in the system)

```py
rule someRule3:
    benchmark: "benchmark_result4.tsv"    
    threads: 10
    shell:
        """
        ./sometool --threads {threads}
        """

rule someOtherRule:
    benchmark: "benchmark_result_other.tsv"    
    threads: 5
    shell:
        """
        ./sometoolv2 --threads {threads}
        """
```

Questions:

- In case 1 and 2, snakemake cannot change what is defined in the shell directive (`--threads 2`), but I think it will reserve 1 thread then run the command. Will it use 1 threads or 2? How does snakemake actually send the job?
- As snakemake says "Rules claiming more threads will be scaled down", how can we make sure that this is not affecting the benchmarking results by scaling down under the hood while we assume results are for the number of threads we specified?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's slightly nuanced but not too complicated.  I'm assuming you are running locally, if you submit to a scheduler, the scheduler will enforce the maximum number of cores a job gets.  E.g. if you submit a job with 2 cores your job will not use more than 2 cores, regardless of the value of threads passed to the command.

Here's the run down with more details following.  Assuming you invoke snakemake with all cores available, 10:

0. Can run 5 jobs, each will start tool with 2 threads.
1. Threads defaults to 1.  Will try to run 10 jobs at once.  Each will call some tool with 2 threads and probably compete with each other a lot.
2. Same as 2
3. Can run 2 jobs, each will start with 2 threads.  So 6 of your cores will be idle.
4. Here rule 3 can run up to one job at a time.  If someOtherRule starts first, rule 3 will wait.  If you only gave snakemake 5 cores as an option, rule 3 will run with 5 threads (the max).

Threads acts like any other resource, limiting how many jobs are run at once.  The value you feed to your command *should* match the number of threads, but doesn't have to.  When you have a mismatch you can get lots of competition or idling cores.  Best practice is to always use `{threads}` in your shell/run/etc if only to not repeat a value multiple times.  Basically, snakemake believes you when you say a rule with use `n` threads and doesn't enforce that constraint on the job once it starts running.

Threads is also special when you don't provide enough threads to snakemake.  If `threads` of a rule is greater than the number of cores you specify, it will be set to the number of cores you specify.  Snakemake will *not* scale down threads just to get a job running if some of your cores are idle (case 4 above).  Instead it waits until enough resources are available to run with the maximum number of threads.  For benchmarking, it won't scale down unless you invoke with fewer cores.  You may get high variance on local machines due to other OS processes (web browsing, virus scanning, etc), but the number of threads should stay the same.

Take home is:

- Always pass in `{threads}` if you are using the `{threads}` directive
- Set the number of threads in your directive to be the highest value where strong scaling is still followed.  That will get your job done fast when there are enough cores and snakemake will scale it down if the user doesn't have enough cores.

  - There are some nuances here with schedulers and when/where you want to parallelize your work.